# How to run java 6 and java 7 simultaneously

Tags: java, windows, server, system

I have java 6 installed in one of my servers running application x. Now I was giving application y that is supposed to run in the same server. However, they "forgot" to tell me that application y needs java 7, not 6. 
After reading a bit on the internet, I realized that it's possible to run multiple versions of java in the same windows box, but I cannot make sense of what to do with the environment variable and how it know when to use java 6 or 7. Does anyone either know what I need to do or of a website where I could find good information?
Thank you!

Comment: Please don't; you're only making yourself more vulnerable/less likely to get newer, more awesome things from Java.  Java 6 isn't even supported, and Java 7 ended support last April, so there's little incentive to not use something newer.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have much of a choice...

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @Makoto: if a third-party product only runs on Java 6, then it only runs on Java 6.  There isn't much a server administrator can do about it.  Nor is a security issue per se, so long as the only thing you're running on the old Java is a trusted application.  But the question is off-topic on SO anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not rely on JAVA_HOME environment variables, most applications can be run using an absolute path. You don't even need to run Java setup.exe on server machine. This quarantees you don't accidentally get Java browser Plugin and version controlling is easier.

- Run Java6 and Java7 setup.exe in one machine say your personal laptop
- Go to `c:\program files\Java\Java_xxx` folder and zip it
- Unzip to a server, say `c:\java\Java_xxx` folder, you should see `Java_xxx\bin\java.exe` file
- Uninstall Java6 and Java7 from laptop if you don't need it
- Server machine may not need JAVA_HOME envvar to mess versions up
- Use JavaJRE or JavaSDK both are fine or side by side everything

Run java application using an absolute path, you may create a shortcut or .bat script to run application.
`c:\java\Java_xxx\bin\java.exe -cp ./lib/myapp.jar;./classes com.package.MyAppMain param1 param2`

Comment: I followed your instructions and everything seems to be fine now. Thank you so much!!! :)